# Is there any SEO differences/considerations between data in LISTS vs TABLES vs DEFINITION LISTS?

Tags: seo, html

Are there any SEO or user-experience considerations between using...

- Tables: `<table> <tr> <td>`
- Lists: `<ul> <li>`
- Definition Lists: `<DL> <dt> <dd>`

Example of each:

https://jsfiddle.net/ey9umph9/2/

Assume each usage is appropriate (aka, if I had data in four rows and five columns, it would obviously be best on a table).

But if there is data that would be appropriate for all three items above, for instance a set of terms and their definitions, is there any consideration/benefit to using one or the other?  or, is it entirely a personal preference of the web developer?

This is not a STYLING question, assume the CSS/display of each is equally and appropriately appealing to users.

*Edit: This link may provide some context:  https://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=7089*

Comment: 'A set of terms and their definitions' sounds like the text book use case for a definition list. Why a table or list would be equally appropriate?

Comment: @TimFountain They would equally be able to show the same information/association. All three of them, barring horrific styling, communicate the same information/association *to the reader*... I'm curious if there is a difference in what either of them communicate *to the machine*, or in this case to SEO.

Comment: HTML is all about _semantics_. The way you communicate to a _machine_ that block of text X is a _definition_ of something is by using markup that indicates that. In practice, the search engine robots have evolved at a much faster pace than HTML and from an SEO point of view it's unlikely to make much difference. But your example of 'data that would be appropriate for all three' just amused me, since a list of definitions is clearly most appropriately a definition list.

Comment: Search engines ignore almost all markup including tables and lists.  Google used to care about some markup such as heading tags but these days relies much more on how text is styled instead of how it is marked up.

Comment: With regards to @StephenOstermiller (s) comment, generally he is right, however, Google does look at HTML mark-up for examining fact linking. While fact links can exist in sentences, special attention to the mark-up you reference specifies fact links that Google pays attention to. These are Ah hah! triggers that Google examines differently specifically for fact links to add to the knowledge graph. These are helpful specifically for SEO. They do not boost search for these elements, however, they can fuel the answer engine which boosts placement if used. Cheers!!

Comment: Perhaps this article will help you https://moz.com/blog/google-structured-snippets